# Hide window using SetWindowPos doesnt hide combobox

Tags: c#, interop

Im trying to hide a window using this line of code

```
SetWindowPos(d, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x0004 | 0x0010 | 0x0080);
```

The SetWindowPos method is the one from user32.dll
Most of the time it works fine, however if a combobox is open when Im hidding the window the list of the combobox remains visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetWindowsPos does not hide the dropdown list because the dropdown list of the combobox is not a child of the combobox, so it is not affected by SetWindowsPos.

(You might want to use Spy++ to see the parent of the dropdown list, which is NULL - meaning the desktop is its parent, in contrast with the combobox control who's parent is the form it is on)

Why not use the Form.Hide() method which properly hides the window and the combobox' dropdown list?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont think I can use Form.Hide() because the window im trying to hide is not in managed code.

Comment: Oh, you didn't specified this from the start. In this case you should use the ShowWindow function from the Win32 API with the SW_HIDE parameter, via interop.

Comment: That did the trick. thank you very much! Do you know if there is any differences in the behavior SetWindowPos and ShowWindow that I need to be aware of?

Comment: None as i'm aware of.I see ShowWindow a more direct way to accomplish what you want (hide the window). SetWindowPos is more generic and I use it when I need to move/resize the window. I see the fact that you can hide the window with a combination of SetWindowPos' arguments more like a side effect.